# FireGestures script to scroll to top of a page instantly

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

FireGestures is an extension/add-on for Firefox that provides mouse gestures functionality. You can create custom scripts for it. There is a built-in gesture for scrolling to top but it is animated which I don't like. Also, I cannot find the script that is being used for it.

I'm trying to create a custom script for instant scroll to top of page effect. I tried document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; and window.scrollTo(0,0); which I found from other questions on StackOverflow but none of them worked.

Comment: Could you use [this?](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp)

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Here you have [full list of firegestures codes](http://www.xuldev.org/firegestures/getscripts.php) hope this helps you, I dont like this extension, weird to use for me, lack of documentation.

Comment: I had a look at that link before. Unfortunately, it is not updated so they don't have the script for scroll to top.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: hmm...not sure what you mean. the question is fine. maybe you don't know the answer.